# C++ Invalid read of size 16, Address is 744 bytes inside a block of size 752 alloc'd

Tags: c++, c, memory, ffmpeg, valgrind

I know there are similar questions to this one but I can't seem to find the solution in my own circumstances.

I've made a program using opengl and ffmpeg that uses a buffer to complete it's operations. Normally, the program runs just fine with no errors whatsoever. However when I run my application using valgrind I get this error:

```
==31277== Invalid read of size 16
==31277==    at 0xD27852: memcpy (string_fortified.h:29)
==31277==    by 0xD27852: scale_internal (swscale.c:947)
==31277==    by 0xD29EE8: sws_scale (swscale.c:1213)
==31277==    by 0x268BBC: Videooio::video_encoder::set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(AVFrame*, SwsContext*) (video_encoder.cpp:441)
==31277==    by 0x268D18: Videooio::video_encoder::get_video_frame(Videooio::OutputStream*) (video_encoder.cpp:486)
==31277==    by 0x269032: write_video_frame (video_encoder.cpp:499)
==31277==    by 0x269032: Videooio::video_encoder::encode_one_frame() (video_encoder.cpp:553)
==31277==    by 0x22BD89: Videooio::Application::main_loop() (Application.cpp:212)
==31277==    by 0x21B007: Videooio::Application::Run() (Application.cpp:70)
==31277==    by 0x219C94: main (main.cpp:22)
==31277==  Address 0x50df9c8 is 744 bytes inside a block of size 752 alloc'd
==31277==    at 0x4849013: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31277==    by 0x21A970: Videooio::Application::Run() (Application.cpp:40)
==31277==    by 0x219C94: main (main.cpp:22)
```

I've diagnosed the problem down to the following lines but I'm not quite sure how to fix it:

Application.cpp

```cpp
void Run()
{
  ...
40   encoder = new video_encoder(width, height, fps, duration);
  ...
      while (second < duration)
     {
      auto* fbo = opengl_engine.glBuffer;

      encoder->set_encode_framebuffer(fbo);
212   encoder->encode_one_Frame();
     }
}
```

video_encoder.h:

```cpp
namespace Videooio{
class video_encoder{
    public:
        video_encoder(int w, int h, unsigned int fps, unsigned int duration);
        
        void set_encode_framebuffer(uint8_t* data, bool audio_only = false);

        void encode_one_frame();
        ~video_encoder();  
    private:
        int write_frame(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, AVCodecContext *c,
                       AVStream *st, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt);

        AVFrame *get_video_frame(OutputStream *ost);

        int write_video_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, OutputStream *ost);

        uint8_t *rgb_data;

        int width;
        int height;
        
        void set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(AVFrame *frame, struct SwsContext *sws_context);
       
    };
}
```

Here is opengl_engine, where fbo is allocated:

```cpp
...
if (posix_memalign((void**)&glBuffer, 128, (gl_width * gl_height * 4) ) != 0) 
{
   ERROR("Couldn't allocate frame buffer ");
   return false;
}
...
```

Here is where I set the rgb_data that is inside the encoder (Probably the culprit too) is set to the allocated fbo:

```cpp
void video_encoder::set_audio_frame(AVFrame* audio, AVSampleFormat* format)
{
    audio_data = *audio;
    input_sample_fmt = *format;
}
```

`rgb_data` is set uninitialized up until this point before it's usage (I've tried mallocing it inside the constructor, which was a horrible practice, but doing so changed nothing.).
And here is where it's used and where valgrind mentions:

```cpp
   void video_encoder::set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(AVFrame *frame, struct SwsContext 
   *sws_context) {
       const int in_linesize[1] = { 4 * width };
       //uint8_t* dest[4] = { rgb_data, NULL, NULL, NULL };
       sws_context = sws_getContext(
               width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
               width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
               SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
440    std::cout << "Address: " << rgb_data << std::endl;
441    sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *)&rgb_data, in_linesize, 0,
442            height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
}
```

I'm not %100 sure whether `rgb_data` is causing this error or not but digging into `sws_scale` and finding where `memcpy` is used shows that `rgb_data` is used inside it.

I've tried changing the buffer size of `glBuffer` to no avail since valgrind allways says `744 bytes inside a block of size 752` the size of which the error mentions is not changing when I change `glBuffer`s size, this led me to believe that `rgb_data` might not be the culprit. But it's still my best bet.

I've looked into these questions but I just can't seem to apply them to my own circumstance.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776831/valgrind-address-is-8-bytes-before-a-block-of-size-16-allocd)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662008/valgrind-giving-error-but-everything-seems-fine)

I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. I'm not sure if it is possible for you to provide one in this case. However, if it is possible, then it would probably make it easier for other people to help you and it would also improve the quality of your question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it has read 16 bytes starting at offset 744 of a block that is 752 bytes long.  744 + 16 gets you to an offset of 760, which is 8 bytes **past the end of your allocated memory block**.  It's warning you of this buffer overrun.  You'll have to investigate to figure out why it's doing that.  The start address of the block appears to be stored in `rgb_data`.

Comment: It's pointing to the video_encoder itself, not the glBuffer. Which is odd because video_encoder doesn't seem to be 752 bytes long.

Comment: we can just google swscale.c and there's a decent (not 100%) chance that line 947 is close to the same line as on your computer: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswscale/swscale.c#L947 - it's copying the strides and it always copies 4 of them. Are there supposed to be 4 strides?

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswscale/swscale.c#L288 here we see that for packed formats the first stride is used and the other 3 are overwritten (original values ignored). So ffmpeg is reading some values from out of bounds, but then ignoring them. Report an ffmpeg bug if you want.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you for pointing me to the right direction, I guessed as much. Like i mentioned when I simply do +8 to `possix_memalign` 's size parameter it does not change anything. Any idea where to head next?

Comment: @user253751 Yes! Line 944 is exactly where my error occurs, about the strides, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I understand that but unfortunately the code itself is a bit long, so I tried my best to include as many details as possible.

Comment: That's interesting.  Might want to disclose what the widths are.  There's often a restriction in lossy encoding technology where image widths must be a multiple of the macro-block size (often 8x8 pixels).  Also *odd* widths are sometimes not supported especially when dealing with 4:2:2 formats.

Comment: @Wyck the program allows me to set width / height on run, so far I've tested with many sizes to no avail. most notably by the writing of this post the width / height were 100/100 and also tested with 1000/1000 during writing. I will try multiples of 8x8 now.

Comment: Turgut.  You should test resolutions that are **not** multiples of 8 and see if you get errors.  e.g. something that is just slightly bigger than a power of 2 is a good choice:  17 is nice or 1025.

Comment: @Wyck apparently I only needed to put `rgb_data` higher in the header file for it to align... Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an ffmpeg bug. ffmpeg is [reading](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswscale/swscale.c#L947) 4 source strides and 4 source pointers but (if the pixel format is packed) [only cares about](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswscale/swscale.c#L288) the first one.

You could pass an array of 4, or add some extra padding to the end of `class video_encoder` so that ffmpeg reads allocated memory, or move rgb_data earlier in the class so that the members after it act as padding. It doesn't matter if there are valid pointers there.

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide small example's to those options?

Comment: @Turgut you want an example of how to make one thing before another or add some extra useless variables or make an array?

Comment: Hmm I've allready tried adding useless variables, to no avail. I couldn't quite understand where I should make the array in.

Comment: Wow putting `rgb_data` at the top of the class worked! Thanks a bunch!